# Center text in 100%-screen-width div in small wrapper

Tags: css

I want to center a div and it's text, in a 100%-screen-width div, which is in a smaller wrapper.

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 800px;
  width: 900px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.box-wrapper {
  width: 1000%;
  position: relative;
  left: -500%;
  background-color: #FF6600;
}

.box {
  background-color: #FF0000;
  width: 600px;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  color: #00FF00;
}

span {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  Random text for wrapper-div

  <div class="box-wrapper">
    <div class="box">
      <span>ABC</span>
      <span>DEF</span>
      <span>GHI</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This code is kind of working but not perfect.
The red div should be moved a bit to the right, also the way
of doing it is not the best in my opinion.

I want a more robust and responsive solution.
To be more clear, it's for the pink division on the bottom
of this website: http://ndvibes.com

There the code is working 99% of the times and reponsive. But on some computers/screens it's 50% off. So I want a less-hacky (without transform etc) and more standard, robust way of getting that effect.

Wrapper 900px > 100%-screen-width coloured div > Centered text in that coloured div.

How can I achieve this the best as possible?
Thanks!

Comment: Does `.wrapper` require a fixed width and height? Should that be responsive/flexible also?

Comment: .wrapper indeed needs a fixed max-width

Comment: Do you mean the content in the bottom purple area to be max width 900px, but the background color takes full page width?

Comment: Width 1000%. You might want to change that.

Comment: @Pangloss No, purple needs to be full-page-width but rest of website max 900px. It needs to be exactly as you can see on the website now (maybe). The code I'm using right now to achieve it is very hacky and unreliable, on some screens/devices it doesn't show up right (text moved 50%)

Comment: @O'Niel have you seen my answer. I think it might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this approach, using absolute positioned pseudo elements. The `outer-space` div with `overflow:hidden` is to prevent a horizontal scroll bar appearing. I have added `padding-top` to the `.wrapper` just so you can see the snippet running in full screen mode.

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}
.outer-space {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top:80px;
}
.wrapper {
  height: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.box {
  background-color: #8904B1;
  margin:0 auto;
  color: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  padding:10px 0;
}
.box-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width:100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.box-wrapper:before, .box-wrapper:after {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  height:100%;
  width:100vw;
  background-color: #8904B1;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
.box-wrapper:before {
  left:-100%;
}
.box-wrapper:after {
  right:-100%;
}

span {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-space">
  <div class="wrapper">
    Random text for wrapper-div
    <div class="box-wrapper">
      <div class="box">
        <span>Crazy full width window</span>
        <span>absolute positioned pseudo elements</span>
        <span>with centered content div and centered text thingy</span>
        <span>all inside of a fixed width page wrapper!</span>
        <br><span>““”̿ ̿ ̿ ̿ ̿’̿’̵͇̿̿з=(•̪●)=ε/̵͇̿̿/̿ ̿ ̿ ̿ ̿’““</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect exactly what I needed. Sure this code is 100% reliable and better than my current?

Comment: I know the `vw` unit isn't supported in IE8. I would trying this out and test it in all the major browsers. It it works properly across browsers, which I think it will, this is a reliable solution.

Answer (score 0):

To center child element, add the following to the parent wrap will center all child.

```
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
```

If you want 100% screen width, use viewport (100vw) for 100% screen width

> ## viewport
>
> The @viewport CSS at-rule contains a set of nested descriptors in a CSS block that is delimited by curly braces. These descriptors control viewport settings, primarily on mobile devices.
>
> **1vw = 1% of viewport width**
>
> **1vh = 1% of viewport height**
>
> **1vmin = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is smaller**
>
> **1vmax = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is larger**
>
> REF: [@viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@viewport)
>
> REF: [Viewport Sized Typography](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 800px;
  width: 900px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.box-wrapper {
  width: 900px;
  max-width: 900px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #FF6600;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.outer-wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  position: relative;
  color: #00FF00;
}

span {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-wrapper">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>Random text for wrapper-div</p>
    <div class="box-wrapper">
      <div class="box">
        <span>ABC</span>
        <span>DEF</span>
        <span>GHI</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But than my wrapper is not max 900px anymore. It needs to stay max 900px, like http://ndvibes.com; the problem is that the big purple div on the bottom needs to fill the whole page.

Comment: Now .wrapper is 100% and .box-wrapper 900px, it needs to be the opposite.